# How can I test two non-numeric data for t-test on Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, t-test

I have a data set of gender and performance ratings in non-numeric raw data form. How can I test them after conversion from Non-numeric?

Comment: You need to share some samples so we know what your problem is

Comment: Isn’t the [T.TEST](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/t-test-function-d4e08ec3-c545-485f-962e-276f7cbed055) function what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
=if(A1="Male",1,0)
```

and would give the ability to count all the 1 values

```
=count()
```

and same with performance

```
=if(B1="First",1,0)
```